# How to enable javascript in my website?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a project to remotely display the data on the P10 Modules. I made the website for it, but whenever I want to retrieve data from the specific webpage on my website I get the error that is mentioned below;

The error I get when I try to retrieve data from the webpage[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyaVL.png)
The URL for the webpage is http://haider.paks.pk/test1/newfile.txt

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
    <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("b2a5a77ff21b1f1b4e9b8d9099c2f834");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://haider.paks.pk/test1/newfile.txt?i=1";</script>
    <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I possibly solve this issue? How to enable javascript in the coding? Where I would do it?

The codes for the web pages are;

**Index page (Main Page)**

```
   <?php
    //include auth.php file on all secure pages
    include("auth.php");
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="form">

    <p>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>!</p>

    <form action="get_msg.php" method="post">
    <p>Select Department </p>
    <br>
    <select name="dept">
      <option value="cs">CS</option>
      <option value="ee">EE</option>
      <option value="btn">BTN</option>
    </select>
    <p>Enter your message:<br />
    <textarea name="sms" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Send it!" onclick="show()"></p>


    </form>
    <script>
    function show() {
        alert("Message send successfully");
    }
    </script>
         <input type="button" name="b1" value="Show History"onclick="location.href='history.php'">


    <p>This is secure area.</p>


    <p><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></p>

    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**get message page (The page that retrieves the sent message from the server**

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php

 require_once('db_con.php');
    ?>


<?php

//echo $_POST["sms"];
 //$sms = $_POST["sms"];
session_start();

$_SESSION["favcolor"] = $sms;
//echo $_SESSION["favcolor"];

    //echo $_POST["sms"];
    $sms = $_POST["sms"];
    $dept=$_POST["dept"];
echo $dept;
if($dept=="cs"){
    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO cs VALUES('','$sms')";
if( $sql_query){
header("location:index2.php?deptt=$dept");
}
}
if($dept=="ee"){
    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO ee VALUES('','$sms')";
if( $sql_query){
header("location:index2.php?deptt=$dept");
}
}
if($dept=="btn"){
    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO btn VALUES('','$sms')";
if( $sql_query){
header("location:index2.php?deptt=$dept");
}
}


if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
{ 
}
else
{
echo " Data insertion error.. ".mysqli_error($con);
}

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM message";
$iid=last_insert_id($sql);
echo "here";
echo $iid;

 ?>


</body>
</html>
```

**Index2 webpage (The webpage that retrieves the message from get message webpage and sends it to the text file **

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php

 require_once('db_con.php');
    ?>


<?php

//echo $_POST["sms"];
 //$sms = $_POST["sms"];
session_start();

$_SESSION["favcolor"] = $sms;
//echo $_SESSION["favcolor"];

    //echo $_POST["sms"];
    $sms = $_POST["sms"];
    $dept=$_POST["dept"];
echo $dept;
if($dept=="cs"){
    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO cs VALUES('','$sms')";
if( $sql_query){
header("location:index2.php?deptt=$dept");
}
}
if($dept=="ee"){
    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO ee VALUES('','$sms')";
if( $sql_query){
header("location:index2.php?deptt=$dept");
}
}
if($dept=="btn"){
    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO btn VALUES('','$sms')";
if( $sql_query){
header("location:index2.php?deptt=$dept");
}
}


if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
{ 
}
else
{
echo " Data insertion error.. ".mysqli_error($con);
}

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM message";
$iid=last_insert_id($sql);
echo "here";
echo $iid;

 ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: That doesn't mean that JS would be disabled. It means the page is broken.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file to `newfile.html` instead of `newfile.txt`?Browser will only parse and render files of specific types as web pages (actually driven by the `Content-Type` header, but web servers will usually set that based on the file's extension).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yes, I started with .html with tags, then .html with only the data (no tags), then I used .txt but every time I get this error. I want my webpage to act like this webpage 

http://projects.flowingdata.com/holidays/current-rates.txt

Comment: @JJJ How would I solve this issue if the page is broken? Is there any solution to it?

Comment: @alldani I have added the codes. I hope you would help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. There is nothing wrong with the code. The only thing due to which this issue raised was that I was using free domain for my website. When I uploaded the same files on a paid hosting service, the issue was resolved and my arduino was able to retrieve the data from the web server.